# Haskell: How to integrate semantic whitespacing into a parser?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm currently writing a language in Haskell, `https://github.com/EdONeill1/HENRYGCL`, and I'm having trouble in figuring out how to allow for a program to be written on multiple lines. Take the following loop that adds 1 onto x until it reaches 10.

```
Henry > x := 1
Henry > if <x<10> [] x := <x+1> [] x := <x+10>
```

I would like the program to be somewhat in the form of:

```
Henry > x := 1
Henry > if <x<10>
[] x := <x+1>
[] x := <x+10>
```

I thought about using the function `space` or `newline` from the `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char` module. This would allow me to recognise (I think) the newline token `\n`. Upon using it the following parser function:

```
ifStmt :: Parser HenryVal
ifStmt =
  do 
     reserved "if"
     cond  <- bExpression <|>
              do 
                _ <- char '<'
                x <- try parseBinary
                _ <- char '>'
                return x
    some (space <|> newline)
    reserved "[]"
    stmt1 <- statement
    some (space <|> newline)
    reserved " []"
    stmt2 <- statement
    return $ If cond stmt1 stmt2
```

I receive the following error when I try following:

```
Henry > x:=1
1
Henry > if <x<10>
Parse error at "Henry" (line 1, column 10):
unexpected end of input
expecting space or lf new-line
Henry > if <x<10>
Parse error at "Henry" (line 1, column 12):
unexpected end of input
expecting space, lf new-line or "[]"
Henry >
```

The first error arises from pressing Enter when I finish typing `>` and the second error arises from pressing Space once then pressing Enter. In both instances a newline wasn't corrected. I'm not sure as well as to what `lf` in `lf new-line` actually means because to my understanding, shouldn't hitting Enter give you a newline?

In another section of my code I have the following, `whiteSpace = Token.whiteSpace lexer`. When I replace the `some (space <|> newline)` with this and press enter after `if <x<10>`, a newline is actually created. However despite being able to write a full if-statement, there's no termination and it just allows me to keep writing as much as I want indefinitely.

I'm quite confused in how to proceed from here. I think my logic using `some (space <|> newline)` is correct insofar as if the program encounters at least one space or newline, a space or newline is made but I know my implementation is incorrect. I thought that maybe `whiteSpace` would lead to somewhere but it seems as if that's another dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser looks fine. The problem here is that `main` currently runs the parser on a single line at a time. You need to accumulate the whole input before running the parser.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Is what you mean that since in the `readPrompt` function, I have `getLine` then everything is contained to a line and multiple lines can't be inputted ?

Comment: That's right, you need to concatenate the result of multiple `getLine` before calling `evalAndPrint`.

Comment: Would using the function `getContents` be off any benefit? It seems that regarding `readPrompt` when I try to concatenate `getLine` like this: `readPrompt prompt = flushStr prompt >> getLine >> getLine`, the first `getLine` is ignored. I know this is due to the nature of `>>` but I'm having trouble in thinking of a way to concatenate `getLine` in `readPrompt` unless I make a function that gets multiple getLines.

Comment: So it looks like using a function that just concats an arbitrary amount of `getLine` functions together works. I just need to figure out how to add it such that it'll work for any program of any arbitrary length. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `getContents` would get all the input your program will ever accept, so it's not suitable for a REPL where you want to give back the control to the user after each command.